# Python Append String inside list just as an element without double quotes

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

Clarification:

Problem here is I want to put content of list1 inside List2. I was doing it wrong way as suggested in comments.

I get a list1 
value4 = [{'PARAMS': ['ProcessingDate=2016-08-29', 'ReRun=Y']}]

The elements of the PARAMS should be suffixed with '-param' string, so I created a new list with elements of value4[0]['PARAMS'] Then removed the square brackets of this list which ended up as string
FINALPARAMS 
`'-param', 'ProcessingDate=2016-08-29', '-param', 'ReRun=Y'`

Then I was trying to insert these values inside another list as elements.

`myNewlist = ['C:\This\Path', 'value2', 'value3', FINALPARAMS, 'value5']`

This gives output with doublequotes around the FINALPARAMS values

`['C:\\This\\Path', 'value2', 'value3', "'-param', 'ProcessingDate=2016-08-29', '-param', 'ReRun=Y'", value5]`

I want to get rid of the double quotes inside this new list

---

Original Question:

This might be a easy solution for Python expert, but i am tired of finding solution. I have done most of the string manipulation I could do, like converting to string and trying out replace etc:

I have my list like below, I need to put the data of `value4` properly inside `mylist without double quotes.

using python 3.5

I get my `value4` like below

```
   value4 = [{'PARAMS': ['ProcessingDate=2016-08-29', 'ReRun=Y']}]
```

I convert it to list like below, I need `-param` as suffix for my each element in `PARAMS`

```
paramlist   = value4[0]['PARAMS']
newparamlist = []
for x in paramlist:
    newparamlist.append('-param')
    newparamlist.append(x)
FINALPARAMS = (str(newparamlist)[1:-1]) #Taking out the squareBrackets
```

`print FINALPARAMS` gives the desired result. i.e.

`'-param', 'ProcessingDate=2016-08-29', '-param', 'ReRun=Y'`

i use the `FINALPARAMS` in below list which prints value like this, i want to get rid of the double quotes and treat the string which i got from `FINALPARAMS` as normal list item inside the `myNewlist`

`myNewlist = ['C:\This\Path', 'value2', 'value3', FINALPARAMS, 'value5']`

`myNewlist` results as follows Observe the DoubleQuote I want to get rid of it so the values are treated as list items

`['C:\\This\\Path', 'value2', 'value3', "'-param', 'ProcessingDate=2016-08-29', '-param', 'ReRun=Y'", value5]`

I lost 4 hours finding the solution, which looked simple for me initially.
I tried converting this `newList` to string and replaced the doubleQuotes but my subprocess.checkoutput looks for proper list item

I tried converting the list to string and do `replace('"','')`  this turned out that it has put 4 backslashes to the windows path which is my first element in the list. and my command gave a error System cannot find the path specified

Comment: Your question is quite messy. Can you try to be more brief and clearly post a simple example with input, code, output and desired output?

Comment: Sorry @NilsWerner, I thought giving more information is better. Probably i should have been concise.

Comment: You should still edit your question to be more concise. Remember, people are reading already answered questions to find solutions to their problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are confusing putting a **list inside a list** and **concatenating two lists**:

```
[1, 2, paramlist, 5]         # [1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
```

is not the same as

```
[1, 2] + paramlist + [5]     # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Instead of using the correct operation you are trying to cast the list to a string to manually remove the square brackets. Needless to say this is the wrong way of doing it.

So i think you are looking for

```
value4 = [{'PARAMS': ['ProcessingDate=2016-08-29', 'ReRun=Y']}]

paramlist = value4[0]['PARAMS']
paramlist = [elem for x in paramlist for elem in ('-param', x)]
myNewlist = ['Value1', 'value2', 'value3'] + paramlist + ['value5']

print (myNewlist)
```

which yields

```
['Value1', 'value2', 'value3', '-param', 'ProcessingDate=2016-08-29', '-param', 'ReRun=Y', 'value5']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer this solved my problem. I have accepted this answer

Comment: Agreed @Nils Werner  No doubt I was horribly wrong in my approach, Thanks for your detailed explanation. I learnt something new today :)